# 1 to many mapping in R

Tags: r, merge, mapping, fuzzy-comparison

I have 1 dataset set and want to **fuzzy matching to itself** if below condition match.

1. Soundex and consonants should be same
2. Gender should be same
3. fuzzy match data if age is +-5 (if 1 row has age 10 then the matching row should have age b/w 5 to 15)

To ease the process I ran Sound Expression function by which I got SoundEX code on names which pronounce similar. Below is the sample dataset.

```
Age2    Gender4 Consonants2 Name_of_Patient_nospace2    SoundEx
5   F   h   Ahoi    A0
31  M   h   Ahoi    A0
35  F   y   AYEE    A0
33  F   y   AAYEE   A0
39  F   y   AYEE    A0
32  F   y   Ayai    A0
35  M   r   Aro A090
35  M   r   ARAAO   A090
33  M   r   ARao    A090
30  M   r   Arei    A090
35  M   r   Aro A090
35  M   r   ARAAO   A090
33  M   r   ARao    A090
30  M   r   Arei    A090
65  M   r   AARI    A090
```

**What will be the code to get 1 to many matching output?
Eg: if we have 2 table both have same records (1,2,3) then output should be as below (as per 1 to n mapping)**

```
1-1
1-2
1-3
2-2
2-3
3-3
```

Here is the sample output (desired output) of above dataset based on 1 to many mapping (for reference purpose, only SoundEx: A0 output is shown).

```
Age2    Gender  Consonants2 Name_of_Patient_nospace2    SoundEx Age2_Copy   Gender_Copy Consonants2_Copy    Name_of_Patient_nospace2_Copy   SoundEx_Copy
5   F   h   Ahoi    A0  5   F   h   Ahoi    A0
31  M   h   Ahoi    A0  31  M   h   Ahoi    A0
35  F   y   AYEE    A0  35  F   y   AYEE    A0
35  F   y   AYEE    A0  33  F   y   AAYEE   A0
35  F   y   AYEE    A0  39  F   y   AYEE    A0
35  F   y   AYEE    A0  32  F   y   Ayai    A0
33  F   y   AAYEE   A0  33  F   y   AAYEE   A0
33  F   y   AAYEE   A0  39  F   y   AYEE    A0
33  F   y   AAYEE   A0  32  F   y   Ayai    A0
39  F   y   AYEE    A0  39  F   y   AYEE    A0
39  F   y   AYEE    A0  32  F   y   Ayai    A0
32  F   y   Ayai    A0  32  F   y   Ayai    A0
```

Comment: What will be the expected output on the given sample data set? Please add that too.

Comment: Added Expected Output of given dataset. Column name with suffix "_Copy" is the 2nd table with same records as 2 tables are required in fuzzy matching.